# What is the best way to develop a Facebook web app and debug it?

Tags: facebook, debugging

Locally I use Eclipse PHP's great PDT plug-in, but when I need to integrate with Facebook
it seems that I have no alternative but to use the vim/local editor without the ability to use
a debugger.
I there any way to keep using Eclipse PDT while developing a Facebook web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in Visual studio, not sure about Eclipse.

VS has a built in webserver so when you are debugging you view the page on http://localhost:x , because facebook apps are viewed in an iframe you can set your app to load from localhost.

When you have done that viewing the facebook app normally in facebook will load the page from your IDEs webserver giving normal debugging.

Then when you are ready to go live either swap over the URL in the app setup to where it is hosted, or create another app with the live URL so you can continue debugging (just remember to have a build script that swaps out your app id/secret if you do this).

Comment: is there any problem with the FB API ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API is just a service (a collection of HTTP requests). You can use any IDE you like, you can even use Notepad!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean IDE, you can use NetBeans or Zend Studio for more rich featured php editor.